# Initializing values in the constructor

Tags: c++

I am making a Tic-Tac-Toe game and I am having a problem in initializing values of attributes in the constructor.
However, you will notice that from line 8-38, I had to repeat the code again as I wanted the user to play the game again when the result is determined. When I did not put the code from the constructor to the RunGame method, it would not repeat.

I tried to remove the code from the Run_Game method but the board won't display again when the game is over.

```
Tic_Tac_Toe::Tic_Tac_Toe()
{
    // Intializing values to attributes of class
    n = 0;
    size = 1;
    player_1 = 'X';
    player_2 = 'O';


    cout << "Welcome to the tic-tac-toe game" << endl;

}


void Tic_Tac_Toe::Run_game()
{
    //Intializing values from 2D array to board
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            matrix[0][0] = '1';
            matrix[0][1] = '2';
            matrix[0][2] = '3';
            matrix[1][0] = '4';
            matrix[1][1] = '5';
            matrix[1][2] = '6';
            matrix[2][0] = '7';
            matrix[2][1] = '8';
            matrix[2][2] = '9';
        }
    }
    int n = 0;
    int size = 1;
    char player_1 = 'X';
    char player_2 = 'O';
Draw_board(matrix,1); // Drawing the board for the game

    while (true) {
        n++;//Increments the value of n by 1 until condition is fulfils
        Input(matrix, player_1,player_2);
        Draw_board(matrix,1);
        if (Results(matrix,player_1,player_2) == player_1) {
            cout << "Player 1 wins" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (Results(matrix,player_1,player_2) == player_2) {
            cout << "Player 2 wins" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (Results(matrix,player_1,player_2) == '/' && n == 9) { // Comparing if result is a draw or not
            cout << "The game ends in a draw" << endl;
            cout << "You should play the game again to find a winner" << endl;
            break;
        }
        Set_players(&player_1, &player_2);
    }
```

Comment: Note: there’s no need for the loops in `Run_game` since you don’t use the variables for anything. Now you’re just setting the values nine times when one time would be enough.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen how do I write the code one time?

Comment: How should somebody answer this question without seeing the definition of the matrix? In the initialisation you can simply write matrix[i][j] = i*3+j+1. Then I guess your are passing the matrix not correct to the subfunctions. This will not work. Please show the code . . .